# Экранирование спецсимволов ' и " для запроса в SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, экранирование

Нужно в БД поместить текстовый файл

```
text = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName, Encoding.Default);
```

В переменную помещается весь файл в "оригинальном" виде. Но при отправке запроса

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Books(txt) VALUES (\'" +
            text + "\');";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

экранирование отсутствует, и на выходе получаю неверный запрос

Text - книга в многабукв, английский или русский (что подразумевает наличие и ', и ").

В БД нужно именно "нормальный вид", без двойных кавычек (если не ошибаюсь, двойные кавычки в запросе к SQLite в базе хранятся как одинарные)

Да, есть способ пройтись по строке и просто везде продублировать кавычки, но повторюсь - многабукв, текстов тоже много. Не знаю, рационально ли это

Есть ли какой метод, которые экранирует все спецсимволы в строке? Или параметр запроса к базе, который отбросит необходимость экранировать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте подготовленные выражения(prepared statements).
Пример:

```
SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection(...);
SqlCommand s = new SqlCommand("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Books(txt) VALUES (@text)", db);
s.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text", text);
s.Prepare();
s.ExecuteNonQuery();
```