# Как убрать экранирование апострофа в c#?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

Беру с сервера имена всех таблиц. После чего пытаюсь получить доступ к таблице по одному из полученному имени.

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM @table", db.getConnection());
command.Parameters.Add("@table", MySqlDbType.String).Value = '`' + nameTable + '`';
```

Но выходит ошибка:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near ''`физические лица - клиенты`'' at line 1

Я понял, что мои апострофы экранируются. Как мне убрать это экранирование? При этом данное экранирование происходит только при передачи sql запроса на сервер. В программе если вывести данную строку в label, то она будет нормальной.
Я пробовал бороться не писать на прямую апостроф, а ставить /x027 - не помогло. Я пробовал делать экранирование апострофа /` - но такой escape-последовательности не существует.
Одинарная кавычка для sql не подходит. Он не воспринимает ее.
Также если передать sql запрос на прямую с именем таблицы, то все работает исправно.

```
"SELECT * FROM `физические лица - клиенты`
```

Но мне необходимо динамически получать имена таблиц и отображать их содержимое.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такая ошибка и с @ и без него. С экранированием и без него. С одинарными кавычками @ не работает. Без него появляется слэш

Comment: \\` -так тоже не работает?

Comment: Есть форма записи @"строка " в ней апострофы ' не нужно экранировать (это за 39-тый прямой апостроф). Обратный апостроф `  не нужно вообще экранировать. Ставьте `  без экранирования.

Comment: @NMD, Так \` пишет что нет такой space-последовательности. Если я ставлю апостроф обратный без экранирования, то выходит ошибка, где показывает мой апостроф с обратным слэшем, хотя я его не ставил и не экранировал.

Comment: @nick_n_a ,С @ тоже не работает, все равно в ошибке показывает, что обратный слэш есть, хотя я его не ставил

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near "\`физические лица - клиенты\`'' at line 1. Слэши обратные в ошибке есть, просто здесь их убирают тоже, они перед апострофом

Comment: Не поможет? Я делал так, правда, в SQLite:
[Экранирование спецсимволов в sql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/825252/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B2-sqlite)

Comment: @AlexGrand , AddWithValue не помогает. Да и разница между ним и Add только лишь в том, что первое определяет тип value самостоятельно. К тому же там вопрос с одинарной ковычкой, а у меня обратный апостроф

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я недавно решил подобную проблему так, правда, в SQLite, но я думаю и тут подойдет: Нужно добавить параметр отдельно, а не собиранием строки/экранированием. т.е cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newValue", newValue);

```
using (SQLiteConnection Connect = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source =" + Application.StartupPath + @"\GridProjectDB.db; version = 3"))
                {
                    Connect.Open();
                    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand
                    {
                        Connection = Connect,
                        CommandText = $@"UPDATE GridProjectTable
                                     SET {col} = (@newValue)
                                     WHERE GUID = '{thisRowObject.GUID}'"
                    };
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newValue", newValue);
                    cmd.Prepare();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Connect.Close();
                }
```

Comment: Благодарю. Решил вопрос такой MySql Командой: $@"SELECT * FROM `{nameTable}`". И даже AddWithValue не потребовалось

Comment: @golzqggg лучшее спасибо - зеленая галочка слева от ответа. Но я бы не советовал использовать ни конкатенацию строки запроса, не `AddWithValue`, потому что и то и другое - костыли, но последнее - определенно лучшее решение, чем предложенная вами интерполяция. Не забывайте про безопасность и SQL иньекции, интерполяция - дырища в этой безопасности. https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/